# How to implement Collapsing dropdown list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

some doubt in flutter.
How to implement  Collapsing dropdown list in Flutter ?
Like this : [Design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTvtN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [ExpansionPanel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html).